# Sparx Enterprise Architect 15.1 issue with Master Document and Report Package

Tags: documentation, enterprise-architect

I try to define more complex project reports. For this, I tried to

1) generate a new diagram (Extended -> Model Diagram)

2) Add both a Master document and a Report Package, and a Model Document

Now my issue is, neither Master nor Report Package are shown in the diagram, and only shown as normal packages in the browser. Only the Model Document is visible as a class.

[image]
left: part of the project browser, right: part of the diagram.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Something weird is going on. That is definitely not standard behavior. Are you sure you don't have any add-ins or automatic scripts running that intervene here?

Comment: We have some add ins, such as the Modeling Assistant (LieberLieber) and some MDG (only from Sparx.) I am absolutely sure it worked some weeks ago, but cannot find out what is wrong. I also stopped my EA Client and restarted it...

Comment: Might be worth to try and disable all add-ins, and also to try with a new empty model.

Comment: @GeertBellekens that solved it. I switched on add-in partially (first half, second quarter,..) until I found the add-in generating that behaviour. It is an old add-in for logging purpose, obviously not compliant to the existing EA.

Comment: Which one was it? You can answer your own question with the details of what you did to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logging add-in I used ("EAlogging") is not compliant with the current version of EA (15.1).

Switching it off solved the issue.